# How Api gateway get back the result of mircoservice in different instance?

Tags: node.js, microservices, webapi

Assume that I have a crud api gateway and a mircoservice, both of them are running on different docker instances.
And I have a message queue as the bridge between them.

When the api gateway receive a http request, then pass tasks to the message queue.

Then the microservice which listening the message queue, pull out the task and process it. When the process is done, how can I tell the api gateway that task is already done and send back the result to the request?

Because the stuff of mircoservice is some kind of stateless, it don't need to know where the task from, but the api gateway doesn't.

Is it a bit dum If I build another message queue for the task result,  then the api gateway keep looping on it to compare the task result with something like id?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

1. **Chain the requests Client -> Gateway -> Service -> Gateway -> Client**

   The gateway will just wait till it gets a response from the service and return it back. But the problem here is that the gateway will be waiting for a response from the service. And as you said if there is a queue that is processing something, there is a good chance that it will take some time, especially if there are lot of items waiting to be processed.
2. **Websockets**

   This allows you to communicate both ways. So you can inform the client that job is done. But not sure how it works with gateways.
3. **Callback URL**

   The client will send the request and will specify some URL that will be called when the job is done. This means that the client will get, e.g., 200 OK back that item was put into the queue but without status of the task. And when the job is done, the service will call the URL defined by the client with the result, so it will push the status to the client instead of waiting for the result.
4. **Pulling status**

   Client -> Gateway -> Service will add the task into the queue and will respond with 200 OK. Then the client will ask for the status in some predefined intervals to get the status of the task. This is not very effective but also an option.